# Appending % Symbol with y-axis values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to appending `%` symbol with y-axis values in `ggplot2`. I used `scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)` but it first multiply the values with `100` and then attach `%` symbol whereas I need something like this `35%` rather than `3,500%`.

```
library(ggplo2)
library(scales)

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()

p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl)

p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl) + scale_y_continuous(labels=percent)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: or just divide the y-axis by 100 in the `aes`: `aes(displ, cty/100)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pasting the "%" onto the values seems to work fine

```
p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl) + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) paste0(x,"%"))
```